# Check all checkboxes at all pages of jQuery DataTable (server side processing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables with **server side processing enabled** and i'm facing the issue with checking all checkboxes at all pages. Below is my code, so help me with solution.
This worked only for current page.

```
$(document).on("ifClicked","#selecAllRec",function(event){
    if(event.currentTarget.checked){
        proCustomerListTbl.api().column(0).nodes().to$().each(function(index){
            $(this).find('.proCustChk').iCheck("uncheck");
        });
    } else {
        proCustomerListTbl.api().column(0).nodes().to$().each(function(index){
            $(this).find('.proCustChk').iCheck("check");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Whatever task you are doing, it is not advisable to implement check-all functionality for all pages which user cannot see. As an example, consider you have implemented "Delete checked" and user selects check all, user is under impression that only those records he sees will be deleted, but with your logic, all will be deleted.

Comment: Totally agree with @PriyankPanchal. Also with server-side data processing only current page data is available to the API (`column(0).nodes()`), you must implement custom routine to delete all records. But once again it's not advisable.

Comment: Yes but i'm not use for delete, i have more than 10000 records and i want to update sold date and units fields etc to all records so i want to check all records with all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have global variable that will store whether all entries should be considered checked or not:

```
var allChecked = false;
```

That value can be switched by your *major* checkbox (I have used plain JS `addEventListener()` instead of jQuery `.on()` for certain extended options):

```
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if($(event.target).is('thead [type="checkbox"]')){
    allChecked = $(event.target).prop('checked');
    $('table').DataTable().draw(false);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
```

And you may render your rows checkboxes according to `allChecked` current value:

```
  drawCallback: function(){
    $(this.api().column(0).header()).html('<input type="checkbox"></input>');
    [...$('#example [type="checkbox"]')].forEach(checkbox => $(checkbox).prop('checked', allChecked));
  }
```

That will not allow you, by any means, to *mark*  current data rows with respect to current ordering/filtering, but you may use `allChecked` variable to restore that selection server side.

Following snippet demonstrates that approach:

```js
//mimic source data
const srcData = [
  {name: 'apple', cat: 'fruit'},
  {name: 'pear', cat: 'fruit'},
  {name: 'carrot', cat: 'vegie'},
  {name: 'cabbage', cat: 'vegie'},
  {name: 'potato', cat: 'vegie'}
];
//initialize global 'allChecked' variable
var allChecked = false;

//initialize datatables
$('table').DataTable({
  dom: 'tp',
  data: srcData,
  pageLength: 3,
  columns: [null, 'name', 'cat'].map(header => ({title: (header || ''), data: header})),
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 0,
    render: () => `<input type="checkbox"></input>`
  }],
  drawCallback: function(){
    $(this.api().column(0).header()).html('<input type="checkbox"></input>');
    [...$('#example [type="checkbox"]')].forEach(checkbox => $(checkbox).prop('checked', allChecked));
  }
});

//header checkbox click handler
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if($(event.target).is('thead [type="checkbox"]')){
    //assign global variable to current state
    allChecked = $(event.target).prop('checked');
    //trigger table re-draw
    $('table').DataTable().draw(false);
    //prevent click from propagation and swapping column ordering
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now i'm facing issue of getting values of selected checkbox. I added value in all checkbox and want to get all selected checkbox values from all pages. Right now on submit i'm getting only for current page selected checkbox values.
o

Comment: Without seeing how exactly you have added new values (whether those are random user inputs or calculated based on some logic, whether they span across pages loaded from server or those that are not yet received, etc) it is hard to suggest how to cope with the issue.

Comment: You may post another question, describing above details and sharing relevant code so we may discuss your issue substantially.